# Elasticsearch reindex api -not able to copy all the documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have set up the destination index `new_dest_index` prior to running a `_reindex` action, including setting up mappings, shard counts, replicas, etc.

I ran the below POST command to copy all the documents from `source_index` to `new_dest_index` but it looks like it runs in the background and copies only some of the documents,  not all the data from `source_index`.

Can someone please help and also if there are any better ways to copy from one index to another?

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_dest_index"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information, such as providing the response you receive when running this? Additionally what is the difference in mapping between the two?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best way to copy from one index to another.

The `reindex` process, if I remember correctly, copies bulks of 10,000 each time from one index to another. You are not seeing all documents in the destination index because the tasks hasn't finished (in the best of the cases).

You can always list the `reindex` tasks with [_cat/tasks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-tasks.html) like:

```
GET _cat/tasks?v
```

If you see a `reindex` tasks in the output, it hasn't finished and you have to wait a little more.  These processes take minutes, even hours, depending of the amount of documents to copy.

However, if you don't see it listed and the documents in one index does not match with the number of copied documents in the other one, the `reindex` process failed and has to be run again.

That last scenario is a bummer when you want to copy all the documents without restrictions.

A way to avoid that las scenario is to [reindex with Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-routing). You can, for instance, run a `reindex` task for all the documents from January to March, another one for documents from April to June and so on.

You can run several `reindex` tasks without overlapping. Be mindful with this because having too much tasks could affect the performance or the health of your cluster.

Hope this is helpful! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!! really appreciate it. will try out and see!!

Answer (score 1):

Kevin had already showed the case where reindex task is not finished yet, I answer the case when reindex process is finished.

Note that _reindex API can cause data inconsistent problems which is the new updated (newly inserted + updated) on `source_index` which happen right after `_reindex` is triggered, is not applied to the `new_dest_index`.

For example, bofore you run the `_reindex`, you add a document:

```
PUT source_index/doc/3
{
  "id": 3,
  "searchable_name": "version1"
}
//responses
{
  "_index": "source_index",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "3",
  "_version": 1,
  "result": "created",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "created": true
}
```

And then you trigger _reindex API, after triggering _reindex, you update your document:

```
PUT source_index/doc/3
{
  "id": 3,
  "searchable_name": "version2"
}
//responses
{
  "_index": "source_index",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "3",
  "_version": 2,
  "result": "updated",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "created": false
}
```

But after the `_reindex` finished, you check the version for the document in `new_dest_index`:

```
{
  "_index": "new_dest_index",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "3",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "id": 3,
    "searchable_name": "version1"
  }
}
```

The same problems can happen for documents which inserted after trigger `_reindex`
 One solution for this is that the first time you reindex and keep version of the `source_index` using `version_type= external` setting for `new_dest_index`, after you traffic your write to `new_dest_index`, you can reindex again from `source_index` to `new_dest_index` to reindex the missing new update after `_reindex` is triggered.
You can check these settings in the [docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-version-types).